# sql - display all the instalments that i can pay

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have a table with many instalments from different customers. Each customer has available balance.

I want to display all the instalments that the customer can paid.

Customer 1 with available balance 400
Customer 2 with available balance 500

Instalment Table:

```
Customer ID       Instalment amount   Available
1                 150                   400
1                 150                   400
1                 150                   400
1                 150                   400
1                 150                   400
1                 150                   400
1                 150                   400
2                 200                   500
2                 200                   500
2                 200                   500
2                 200                   500
2                 200                   500
2                 200                   500
```

**Below are the Results that i want**

```
Customer ID       Instalment amount   Available
1                 150                 400
1                 150                 400
2                 200                 500
2                 200                 500
```

**the code below is not working**

```
DECLARE @DrACAvailable decimal,
        @PayAmount decimal,
        @RunningTotal decimal

SET @RunningTotal = 0

DECLARE rt_cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT T2.PayAmount, T2.DrACAvailable
FROM LoanAutoPayTransactions T2 
INNER JOIN LoanAutoPayTransactions T1 on T2.LRAC=T1.LRAC


OPEN rt_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @PayAmount, @DrACAvailable

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
  SET @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + @PayAmount
  IF @RunningTotal >= @DrACAvailable BREAK
  UPDATE LoanAutoPayTransactions SET  PayAmount=@RunningTotal WHERE StartDate=(SELECT MIN(T2.StartDate) FROM LoanAutoPayTransactions T2 WHERE T2.LRAC=LRAC)


  FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @PayAmount, @DrACAvailable

 END

CLOSE rt_cursor
DEALLOCATE rt_cursor
```

Comment: I don't understand how the result relates to the source table. How are the two rows per customer in the results selected? Could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: The customer with ID 1 has available balance 400 euro. How many instalments can pay with 400 euro. from the 7 instalments only 2 can pay. 150 + 150 =300 euro. he cannot paid 3 instalments because 150 + 150 +150 = 450 euro

Comment: A couple of additional questions: don't you want the date (which I guess is the startdate) of the instalment too to be able to tell which instalments the customer can pay? And is LRAC the customer ID?

Comment: YES LRAC IS THE CUSTOMER. NO I DON'T CARE ABOUT THE DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not completely sure what you want I made a try. The output is a table variable but it could easily be changed to an update query or something else. Please give it a try and see if it gives the result you want:

```
DECLARE @DrACAvailable decimal,
        @PayAmount decimal,
        @RunningTotal decimal,
        @CustomerID int,        
        @CurrentCustomerID int

SET @RunningTotal = 0

DECLARE @OutputTable table(
    LRAC int,
    PayAmount decimal,
    DrACAvailable decimal);

DECLARE PaymentCursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT LRAC, PayAmount, DrACAvailable
FROM LoanAutoPayTransactions ORDER BY LRAC, StartDate

OPEN PaymentCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM PaymentCursor INTO @CustomerID, @PayAmount, @DrACAvailable

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
  IF @CurrentCustomerID != @CustomerID SET @RunningTotal = 0
  SET @CurrentCustomerID = @CustomerID
  PRINT 'Processing customer id: ' + CAST(@customerid AS VARCHAR)
  SET @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + @PayAmount  

  IF @RunningTotal <= @DrACAvailable INSERT @OutputTable (LRAC, PayAmount, DrACAvailable) VALUES (@CustomerID, @PayAmount, @DrACAvailable)

  FETCH NEXT FROM PaymentCursor INTO @CustomerID , @PayAmount, @DrACAvailable

 END

CLOSE PaymentCursor
DEALLOCATE PaymentCursor

-- Print the output table
SELECT LRAC AS 'Customer ID', PayAmount AS 'Instalment amount', DrACAvailable AS 'Available' FROM @OutputTable
```

Answer (score 1):

This is full working example without cursors, any temporary tables or table variable tables - it can be used in view or user define in-line function:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

    DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
    (
         [CustomerID] BIGINT
        ,[InstalmentAmount] SMALLINT
        ,[Available] SMALLINT
    )

    INSERT INTO @DataSource ( [CustomerID], [InstalmentAmount], [Available])
    VALUES   (1, 150, 400)
            ,(1, 150, 400)
            ,(1, 150, 400)
            ,(1, 150, 400)
            ,(1, 150, 400)
            ,(1, 150, 400)
            ,(1, 150, 400)
            ,(2, 200, 500)
            ,(2, 200, 500)
            ,(2, 200, 500)
            ,(2, 200, 500)
            ,(2, 200, 500)
            ,(2, 200, 500)


    ;WITH RankedDataSource ( [RecordID], [CustomerID], [InstalmentAmount], [Available] ) AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [CustomerID] ORDER BY [CustomerID] ASC) AS [RecordID]
              ,[CustomerID]
              ,[InstalmentAmount]
              ,[Available]
        FROM @DataSource
    ), 
    DataSource ( [RecordID], [CustomerID], [InstalmentAmount], [Available], [CurrentAvailable], [Level] ) AS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT  CAST(0 AS BIGINT)
                        ,[CustomerID]
                        ,[InstalmentAmount]
                        ,[Available]
                        ,[Available]
                        ,0 AS [Level]
        FROM RankedDataSource 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT RecursiveMember.[RecordID]
              ,RecursiveMember.[CustomerID]
              ,RecursiveMember.[InstalmentAmount]
              ,RecursiveMember.[Available]
              ,AnchorMember.[CurrentAvailable] - RecursiveMember.[InstalmentAmount]
              ,AnchorMember.[Level] + 1
        FROM RankedDataSource AS RecursiveMember
        INNER JOIN DataSource AS AnchorMember
            ON RecursiveMember.[CustomerID] = AnchorMember.CustomerID
            AND RecursiveMember.[RecordID] = AnchorMember.[Level] + 1
            AND AnchorMember.[CurrentAvailable] - RecursiveMember.[InstalmentAmount] > 0
    )
    SELECT   [CustomerID]
            ,[InstalmentAmount]
            ,[Available]
    FROM DataSource
    WHERE [Level] > 0
    ORDER BY [CustomerID]
            ,[InstalmentAmount]
            ,[Available]


SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

The important part is the [Recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). In most cases, the use of CTE over Cursors lead to better performance. You are free to check what will suit your needs best.